# Delete child with removeChildAt without delete the last child

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, removechild

I'm now making a program and I want to delete all child except the 1st five child. I'm using this program :

```
while (numChildren > 6) {
        removeChildAt(6);
}
```

But I have another problem now. I don't want the last 3 child of the stage be deleted too. Is there a way to make it happen?

Comment: Better would be to use layers (Sprite) and organize your display list in a much more efficient way. Putting all your object in the same display list level is poor programming.

Answer (score 1):

If it possible it will be more reliable to delete children according to theirs name, not index.

But if not, you can just increase number in your condition.

```
while (numChildren > firstChildrenCount + lastChildrenCount) {
    removeChildAt(firstChildrenCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nFromStart : int = 5; // number of children to remain in the start
var nFromEnd   : int = 3; // number of children to remain in the end
for (var childI: int = numChildren - nFromEnd - 1; childI > nFromStart - 1; childI--)
{
  removeChildAt(childI);
}
```